# Buffer Solution Error with DFRobot FireBeetle ESP8266 and DFRobot Gravity: Analog pH Sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, esp8266

I'm currently using a DFRobot FireBeetle ESP8266 and the DFRobot Analog pH Sensor and having lots of problems.

Firstly the FireBeetle didn't support the `strupr` function in the DFRobot pH Library so had to make a pull request for them to change the function:
[PR](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_PH/pull/7)

I then took the [example software](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__Analog_pH_Sensor_Meter_Kit_V2_SKU_SEN0161-V2) from DFRobot and uploaded.
I connected Positive to VCC, Ground to GND and the data wire to A0 on the FireBeetle.
after this it would output `ph:nan`.
After some research I found there was something wrong with the EEPROM and added this to the libraries code: [@brian190915](https://forum.core-electronics.com.au/t/dfrobot-gravity-analog-ph-sensor-kit-v2-unable-to-calibrate/6139/6) and it started giving me values, however it still wouldn't recognise what buffer was what
I tried resetting the EEPROM using DFRobots code: [code](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__Analog_pH_Sensor_Meter_Kit_V2_SKU_SEN0161-V2)

Should I give up and just get a NodeMCU or is there something I'm missing...

Please Help!!

edit: If I add the probe to the 4pH buffer solution it gives me a result of temperature:25.0^C  pH:-0.42 Voltage:2817.38

Comment: Arduino is C++ but it doesn't come with Standard Library, so not every library or every framework has to implement full ANSI standard, especially for something trivia like `striper`.  A library also does not have to support all the MCUs available in the market.

Comment: What make you think a NodeMCU will work, giving that both are ESP8266 based development boards? The example is based on 5V MCUs, didn't change the the formula for conversion based on 3.3V MCU you are using?

Comment: @hcheung, I know not all boards have be supported however considering this is one of a very select amount of pH sensors on the market designed for Arduino I thought it would, not good research on my end.

Comment: @hcheung In the example software it does let you change the voltage variable in the definitions part however the DFRobot FireBeetle has a 5v VCC so didnt change it. As for thinking the NodeMCU would work I talked to the guy who maintains the library and he said it was because of the ADC on the FireBeetle but on further inspection it seems to be all ESP based boards (should've read the README.md in the repo...)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that the DFRobot pH sensor v2 doesn't support the ESP(32 or 8266) chips and therefore this will just not work.

I'm not 100% sure why, apparently it has something to do with the ADC on the chips. I'm now contacting other suppliers to see if there's a better solution

Sorry if anyone finds this in desperation and finds there's no solution. Maybe one day the devs at the [DFRobot_PH Library](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_PH) will add compatibility if it's possible!

Comment: Both ESP32 and ESP8266 probably not a good choice for reading ph values as the ADC for ESP32 and ESP8266 are not linear. They are also quite noisy due to the on-board WiFi radio. The native ADC of ESP8266 is limited to 1V input, some ESP8266 boards add a voltage divider to make it works for 3V input, some don't add the voltage dividers. With those have the voltage divider, the high impedance make it difficult to get a consistent reading as well...

Comment: Found a company that makes a pH sensor that has a chip on it that communicates via I2C. Gonna see if that helps!